# How can i limit access to the aws-cognito service?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to limit the access to my cognito service.

My scope is to filter all the calls to cognito adding a server layer that allow me to do specific actions when the user uses the service.

I know that triggering events is the right way to do this but the events in cognito are very limited and a lot of stuff can not be done. For example if the Authentication fails for some reason the `postAuthentication` event is not triggered.

Another use case can be the validation of the attribute, or limit the reading of some attribute.

The only idea I've is to hide the `IdentityPoolId` or the `UserPoolClientId` but seems pretty unsafe.

Comment: Don't put Cognito logic on the front end and put it in a Lambda function behind API Gateway which interacts with Cognito?

Comment: Yes, this was my first approach, what I was looking for was a way to avoid the access from the client. Now I' know that I've to create the pool with a SecretKey and use it in the call.

Comment: Although honestly if you're looking for a good identity solution it's not Cognito, for example you can't search a pool by CUSTOM attribute, so unless it's just a basic auth solution you're after you're better making your own JWT solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches in using AWS Cognito UserPools.

1. Using Hosted UI.
2. Using the SDKs/RESTAPI and Implement Your Own API and UI interface.

**Using Hosted UI**

If you go with the first option, pretty much of the things are handled by AWS and the control you have is limited. However, you can do certain configuration using triggers. On the other hand, you have lesser risks from your side since you are maintaining a limited code.

**Using the SDKs/RESTAPI**

If you go with the second option, you can limit Cognito UserPools as required putting the logic inside your own code. This allows limiting access as you desire. However, you have to write custom code to [authenticate and signup users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

**Mix of Both**

It is also possible to use a mix of these approaches. For example, you can write custom code for signup but for sign in use hosted UI.

**Custom Attributes and Claims**

Also if you plan to return attributes based on your custom rules, use the trigger Pre token generation. Amazon Cognito invokes this trigger before token generation allowing you to customize identity token claims.

Note: A similar approach can be done for the Cognito Identity Pools.

Comment: I was thinking about following the second way but what I cannot figure out is how to avoid the user to access directly to the cognito endpoint `https://cognito-idp.someregion.amazonaws.com/1234455678`

The only way I've found is to wrap everything behind my service and hide the UserPooilId and  ClientId. This seems a a bit unsecure.
I haven't found a way to set a `secret` to limit access.

Comment: Sorry... I've finally found the page that talk about it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html

It seems, reading the docs, that if I create a secret, then I've to use it in every call. Thanks again.